# Kotlin JPA: How to deal with @OneToOne initialization

Tags: kotlin

In Java I was doing this:

```
public class User {

    //one-to-one
    private Profile profile = new Profile(this);        

}

public class Profile {

    private User user;

    public Profile(User user) {
        user.setProfile(this);
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

So I just was creating a user and profile was creating *automatically*. Now
I cannot understand how to do it with Kotlin's primary constructor:

```
class User(

    var profile: Profile = Profile(this) //error, since `this` is not in that context

)

class Profile (

    var user: User?

) {

    constructor(user: User): this(user)

}
```

How would you deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
class User {
    var profile = Profile(this)
}


class Profile(var user: User?) {

}
```